# Binding ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

How to solve problem of changing collection content?

One approach is to clear collection and using foreach loop add new content. Collection must change in runtime and because sometimes I have half a million elements to add, It's take too long and not acceptable to me.

When try
 `_myObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>(_anotherCollection);`
binding to view is broken (referencing old collection)

Is it possible to solve this problem an how?

Answer (score 2):

If your binding to the view is broken after assigning the new collection, you should properly implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the property of your collection.

Edit: example

```
// implement the interface on your viewmodel
public class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<UIElement> collectionBackingField;

    public  ObservableCollection<UIElement> Collection
    {
        get { return collectionBackingField; }
        set
        {
           if(value != collectionBackingField)
           {
              collectionBackingField = value;

              // call the method that notifies all observers of the changes
              NotifyPropertyChanged();
           }
        }
    }
 }
```

Please note that now all changes that the UI needs to know about *must* be through the property. No setting the private backing field manually from anywhere in code.

Comment: Your ViewModel needs to implement the interface above. Your property must then call PropertyChanged with the name of the property. The ObservableCollection already does that internally, which is why adding elements already works, but switching the whole collection does not.